# How do you show that $H = \sigma ^2$ is a normal subgroup of $D_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Consider $D_{12}$, the dihedral group of order $12$. This is the group of symmetries of the regular hexagon. Label the vertices of the hexagon clockwise as $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. Let $\sigma = (1 2 3 4 5 6)$ and $\tau = (2 6)(3 5)$. Regard $D_{12}$ as the group $D_{12} = \{e, \sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4, \sigma^5, \tau, \sigma\tau, \sigma^2\tau, \sigma^3\tau, \sigma^4\tau, \sigma^5\tau \}$.

How do you show this? Show that $H = \sigma ^2$ is a normal subgroup of $D_{12}$

Comment: $H$ is not properly defined. Is it the subgroup generated by $\sigma^2$?

Comment: It suffices to check the definition of a normal subgroup on generators. So basically, you just compute $\sigma \sigma^2 \sigma^{-1}$ and $\tau \sigma^2 \tau^{-1}$. The first one is clear and the second one yields $\sigma^4$. Just check it.